# session/authentication loop

Tags: php, session, authentication

I have a loop in this piece of code (the user gets thrown back to the login page). The problem portion is this

```
else if (!$session_id){
    //if user is not logged in, send to the login page
    header("Location:" . $Config_live_site . "/user_events/login.php");
    exit;
}
```

I have a feeling that this is something to do with all the nested if statements. If this "else if" from above is removed, the user can be logged in and all session functionality works fine. Here is the code:

```
    //check if the user has clicked on a submit button in a login form in login.php
if (isset( $_POST['submit'] )) {
    $username   = $_POST['username'];
    $pass       = $_POST['password'];
    if (!$username) {
        echo "<script>alert('Please enter username'); document.location.href='index.php?option=login$string_2';</script>\n";
    }
    if (!$pass) {
        echo "<script>alert('Please enter a password'); document.location.href='index.php?option=login$string_2';</script>\n";
    }
    else {
        $pass = md5( $pass );
    }
//set up user object and start a new session
    $user = new user();
    $database->get_user(&$user, $username, '1');
        if (!strcmp( $user->user_pass, $pass)) {
            session_name( 'login' );
            session_start();
            $logintime  = time();
            $session_id = md5( "$user->username$user->user_type$logintime" );
            $database->set_session($user, $session_id, $logintime);
            $_SESSION['session_id']         = $session_id;
            $_SESSION['session_username']   = $user->username;
            $_SESSION['session_usertype']   = $user->user_type;
            $_SESSION['session_logintime']  = $logintime;
            session_write_close();
        // cannot using mosredirect as this stuffs up the cookie in IIS
                if ($suboption) {
                echo "<script>document.location.href='index.php?$string';</script>\n";
                } else {
                echo "<script>document.location.href='index.php?option=subscriber_home';</script>\n";
                }
                exit();
        } else {
        echo "<script>alert('Incorrect Username and Password, please try again'); document.location.href='index.php?option=subscribe$string_2';</script>\n";
        exit();
        }
}
else if (!$session_id){
    //if user is not logged in, send to the login page
    header("Location:" . $Config_live_site . "/user_events/login.php");
    exit;
}



//session starts 
session_name( 'login' );
session_start();
if ($option == 'logout') {
    require 'logout.php';
    exit();
}

$user = new user();
$user->username = $_SESSION['session_username'];
$user->user_type = $_SESSION['session_usertype'];
$session_id = $_SESSION['session_id'];
$logintime = $_SESSION['session_logintime'];
```

Comment: who knew I had to click on the checkmark? Now I know.

Comment: Why are you making your own session id? PHP does that for you already when you do `session_start()`, and you can retrieve the value with `session_id()`.

Comment: The problem is you are trying to use your session_id before you've even set up the session!

Comment: Your even bigger problem is that you are storing usernames in the db in plaintext!

Comment: BenLee Why is storing usernames in plaintext bad? I understand passwords, but he has at least attempted to hash his passwords, although md5 isn't the safest.

Comment: the code does not work with just else statement, so it has nothing to do with session id and something to do with if/else structure

Answer (score 1):

This code is very messy and I can't completely help you without knowing what your database object is and how it runs, but do something like this. It will simplify your code heaps.

```
session_start();
try{
    if(!isset($_POST['submit']))
        throw new exception('No Post Data Found.');

    if(!isset($_POST['username']))
        throw new exception('Please enter a username.');

    if(!isset($_POST['password']))
        throw new exception('Please enter a password.');

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $password = md5($password);

    //CHECK IF USER CREDENTIALS ARE CORRECT HERE
    #$result = database results as object.
    $valid_credentials = true;

    if(!$valid_credentials)
        throw new exception('Your credentials were incorrect.');

    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    $_SESSION['user_type'] = $result->user_type;
    $_SESSION['logintime'] = time();

    echo '<script>document.location.href="success.php";</script>'
catch (Exception $E){
    echo "<script>alert('$E->getMessage()'); document.location.href='login.php'; </script>";
}
```

Some of these practices I wouldn't recommend, but I tried to fit it in with your code as best as I could. You ovbiously need to add the database object into the code.

I would also rather user header('Location:'); Than a javascript script, but I used your existing tools.

Goodluck!